# Sort a NSArray of numbers in ascending order but send zeros at the end

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I have a simple `NSArray`, containing `NSNumber`s.

I sort the array in an ascending order this way :

```
NSSortDescriptor *lowestToHighest = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];
[_scores sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:lowestToHighest]];
```

My problem is, I'd like the `NSNumber`s containing `0` to be at the end rather than at the beginning. Here is the kind of array I may have to sort (containing some empty `NSNumber`s just for the example):

```
0
25
12
0
8
0
```

My code of course sorts the array like this:

```
0
0
0
8
12
25
```

What I would like is this:

```
8
12
25
0
0
0
```

Of course I could re-order it manually by removing the lines with `0` and adding them at the end, but I'm looking for the cleanest solution possible.

Comment: How is `8, 12, 0` either in ascending or descending order? How did you manage to store `nil` in an `NSArray`? Or are you sure you have `NSNumber` instances? Aren't they `NSString`s, rather?

Comment: @H2CO3 agreed about how author managed to store nil values in representation of NSNumber in NSArray

Comment: It's an ascending orders, except for the value **0**, which is sent a the end of the array. They are in fact not "nil" objects, but non-initialized NSNumbers. The appear in the debug console as **[5] id 0x00000000**

Comment: I removed them from the post, as it sure was strange. Sorry about that.

Comment: @rdurand `0x00000000` is the `NULL` pointer -> **they are actually `nil`.** How did you put those in the array? Is this some kind of `CFArray` bridging?

Comment: @H2CO3: It's a simple NSMutableArray, created with **[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0], [...], nil];**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sort the array using a [comparator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW6).

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {

    if ([obj1 integerValue] == 0 && [obj2 integerValue] == 0)
    {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }
    if ([obj1 integerValue] == 0)
    {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;            
    }
    if ([obj2 integerValue] == 0)
    {
         return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }

    if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) 
    {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) 
    {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Comment: Looks like what I was looking for.. Thanks ! I thought of using a comparator but couldn't make it work.

Comment: @gokhancokkececi You mean id1 and id2 - that was clearly a typo, now fixed.

Answer (score 4):

This will solve your problem,

```
NSArray *sortedScores = [_scores sortedArrayUsiHelperComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2){
    if([obj1 integerValue]==0 && [obj2 integerValue]==0){
        return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedSame;
    }else if([obj1 integerValue]==0){
        return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedDescending;
    }else if([obj2 integerValue]==0){
        return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    if([obj1 integerValue] >[obj2 integerValue]) return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedDescending;
    if([obj1 integerValue] <[obj2 integerValue]) return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedAscending;
    return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedSame;

}];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think JeremyP's answer is more accurate as he compares *[id1 integerValue] == 0* instead of *obj1==nil*. In my case, I want the zeros to be at the end, not the nil objects.

Comment: in your question, there were nil values. I wrote the code for that. You have changed the question. Now check !

Comment: You can't put `nil`s in an `NSArray` anyway.

Comment: @JeremyP, this is how to add null values: [_scores addObject:[NSNull null]];

Comment: @ThilinaHewagama yes, but `[NSNull null]` is not `nil`. [NSNull null] is an object that represents the null value in collections which can't hold nil. A placeholder, if you will.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

- Step 1: sort the array.
- Step 2: move the zeroes to the end of the array.

**Method 2:**

- Step 1: write a comparator function that orders `0` after any other value.
- Step 2: sort the array.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm looking for, as I said in my question.

Comment: @Monolo: When I posted my comment, Caleb had only suggested the first method. I said in my question, that I knew I could do this, but I was looking for something cleaner than "sort then move the zeros". Method 2 is exactly what JeremyP said in his answer, which came out before Caleb edited his own.

Answer (score 1):

@JeremyP's answer provides proper sorting, and is probably what you are after.

However, for completeness a way to do it with filters and the standard `compare:` method:

```
NSArray *numbers = @[@12, @0, @10, @15, @0, @3];

NSArray *sortedPositiveNumbers = [[numbers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self > 0"]] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
NSArray *zeroes = [numbers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self = 0"]];

NSArray *result = [sortedPositiveNumbers arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:zeroes];
```

Thanks to Caleb for the spark.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSPredicate` to filter the values you do not want..

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self > 0"];
NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [[_scores filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
NSSortDescriptor *lowestToHighest = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];
[filteredArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:lowestToHighest]];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I believe this will remove all the zeros, right ? I'd like to keep them in the array, but at the end. Thanks anyways, this may serve me well in the future.

Comment: @rdurand yes that code removes all the values lower than 0 in 1 line. and after that it will sort based on the order you want.